# Android-WebRTC: MediaStream.removeVideoTrack is called after setting local description

Tags: java, android, scala, webrtc

We are developing an Android Application with Scala, WebRTC and the Java SDK. Our current task consists of receiving the remote track that is sent in a second SDP negotiation when the Callee enables video. Thus the Caller is accessing that video track in the `onAddTrack` method of the peer-connection observer. In fact, the track is contained in the Array of MediaStreams, and then we are able to attach it to the VideoRenderer via a ProxySink - pretty much like in this example: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/examples/androidapp/src/org/appspot/apprtc/CallActivity.java#133.

This is the piece of code in charge of that:

```
override def onAddTrack(rtpReceiver: RtpReceiver, mediaStreams: Array[MediaStream]): Unit = {
     info("FLOW: onAddTrack")

     rtpReceiver.SetObserver(rtpObserver)

     call.getCallType match {
       case BothVideo(CallRoles.Caller) | RecvPeerVideo(CallRoles.Caller) => {
         if (mediaStreams.size > 0) {
           val mediaStream = mediaStreams(0)
           val videoTracks: Buffer[VideoTrack] = mediaStream.videoTracks.asScala

           this.remoteMediaStream = Some(mediaStream)

           info(s"FLOW: onAddTrack, call-type: ${call.getCallType}")

           if (call.callerShouldReceiveVideo(call.getCallType) && videoTracks.size > 0) {
             info(s"FLOW: onAddTrack, enabling video-track")

             val videoTrack: VideoTrack = videoTracks(0)

             mediaStream.addPreservedTrack(videoTrack)
             videoTrack.setEnabled(true)
             videoTrack.addSink(flowManager.remoteProxySink)

            ...
           }
         }
       }
```

The problem is that we are not able to get the frames from the Callee's remote track, and this is a bit surprising since we were already able to successfully set the Caller's remote track and render the frames when the Caller initiates the call with video and has to send the remote track to Callee.

We have detected that dispose is being called on the MediaStream (https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/MediaStream.java#75)  right after setLocalDescription is called in the SdpObserver set when creating the answer, and we think this might be cause of our issue.

Creating answer:

```
pcConn.setRemoteDescription(sdpObserver, sdp)
peerConn.createAnswer(sdpObserver, WebRTCCall.sdpMediaConstraints())
```

In SdpObserver:

```
override def onCreateSuccess(sdp: SessionDescription) = {
 ...
 peerConn.setLocalDescription(this, sdp)
 ...
}
```

What can be triggering the MediaStream.dispose method inside native setLocalDescription ?

**Update**
We found something interesting in the sdp, video track seems to have sendonly direction.

```
    v=0
    o=- 2191449863069826960 3 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2 3
    a=msid-semantic: WMS stream0
    m=audio 56825 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 105 13 110 113 126
    c=IN IP4 35.167.127.194
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:2294452033 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.2.159 60968 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:559267639 1 udp 2122202367 ::1 39373 typ host generation 0 network-id 2
    a=candidate:1510613869 1 udp 2122129151 127.0.0.1 56438 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
    a=candidate:1876313031 1 tcp 1518222591 ::1 59473 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 network-id 2
    a=candidate:344579997 1 tcp 1518149375 127.0.0.1 47922 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 network-id 1
    a=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 201.233.49.70 60968 typ srflx raddr 192.168.2.159 rport 60968 generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:1600295039 1 udp 41885439 35.167.127.194 56825 typ relay raddr 201.233.49.70 rport 60968 generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3811514541 1 udp 41885695 34.221.141.99 60923 typ relay raddr 201.233.49.70 rport 60968 generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:GGkb
    a=ice-pwd:owqpzSht95NQb92cgzKNkQmJ
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 45:76:5A:81:C1:CD:6B:C8:17:C6:CB:7B:20:CD:C6:DD:59:A3:DC:11:47:78:D3:E1:E1:EE:55:1F:83:A5:32:E4
    a=setup:passive
    a=mid:0
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=extmap:2 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
    a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
    a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
    a=sendrecv
    a=msid:stream0 audio0
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    a=ssrc:1249625177 cname:IgXNTJvPXp2HndWi
    m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:GGkb
    a=ice-pwd:owqpzSht95NQb92cgzKNkQmJ
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 45:76:5A:81:C1:CD:6B:C8:17:C6:CB:7B:20:CD:C6:DD:59:A3:DC:11:47:78:D3:E1:E1:EE:55:1F:83:A5:32:E4
    a=setup:passive
    a=mid:1
    a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
    a=extmap:13 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:12 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
    a=extmap:2 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:11 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
    a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
    a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
    a=extmap:8 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
    a=extmap:9 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
    a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
    a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
    a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
    a=sendonly
    a=msid:stream0 video0
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=96
    a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:99 apt=98
    a=rtpmap:100 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:101 apt=100
    a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
    a=ssrc-group:FID 1487952389 3127747783
    a=ssrc:1487952389 cname:IgXNTJvPXp2HndWi
    a=ssrc:3127747783 cname:IgXNTJvPXp2HndWi
    m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    b=AS:30
    a=ice-ufrag:GGkb
    a=ice-pwd:owqpzSht95NQb92cgzKNkQmJ
    a
```